# how to sum two columns at left and display total in third column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table similar to below

```
Date     | institution | qty1 | qty2
1 Aug 12 | xyz         |  0   | 5
1 Aug 12 | xyz         |  0   | 17
1 Aug 12 | abc         | 12   | 0
2 Aug 12 | abc         | 33   | 0
2 Aug 12 | xyz         | 0    | 57
```

I want output similar to below

```
Date     | ABC     | XYZ  | Total
1 Aug 12 | 12      |  22  | 34
2 Aug 12 | 33      |  57  | 90
Total    | 45      | 79   | 124
```

Now I have written a query which displays only first three columns. I don't know how to add the last total column

```
select date, sum (case when institution = 'abc', qty1 else 0 end) as ABC,
sum(case when institution =  'xyz', qty2 else 0 end) as XYZ
group by date
with rollup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close - I think this should do it:

```
select
  date
, sum (case when institution = 'abc' then qty1 else 0 end) as ABC
, sum(case when institution =  'xyz' then qty2 else 0 end) as XYZ
, sum(qty1+qty2) as Total
from mytable
group by date
with rollup
```

Here is a [link to this example on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9004/1).

Comment: @DanJ No, the conditionals are not required, because the `else` branch is always zero, and because there are no other choices other than `'abc'` and `'xyz'`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ah, true. I didn't read the sample data closely.